# EmberJS: model 'isLoaded" but I can't access its properties

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Somewhere in my code, I hit a bug. I put a breakpoint to try and see what is happening. When I inspect the object "foo" in the console I get:

```
foo.toString() > "<App.Foo:ember661:174009>" // all good
foo.get('isLoaded') > true 
foo.get('isValid') > true
```

Yet:

```
foo.get('name') > null // Whereas it definitely has a name.
```

When I look at the Network tab in the developer tools, I can see that it is still "finishing" to load the record. For the corresponding URL, it says: "pending".

What is this model state? How do you know when a model is "fully" ready?

**UPDATE**: per my comment to Mike, I should have added that I am inspecting this record within a registerBoundHelper function. So I guess there is a context issue that I am missing. Indeed:

```
... foo template ...
{{ name }} // properly set to a value
{{ my_helper this }}

... helpers ...
Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper('my_helper', function(foo) {
    return foo.get('name'); // name property is null!!
});
```

I must be missing something obvious?

Thanks,
PJ

Comment: Are you loading from JSON? If so, are you sure it's valid?

Answer (score 1):

> What is this model state?

Can't tell given the info you provided, but to find out from console you could try this:

```
foo.stateManager.get('currentPath') > should be something like "rootState.loaded.saved"
```

Then have a look at [states.js source code](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/system/model/states.js) for details on that state.

> How do you know when a model is "fully" ready?

Depends what you mean by *fully* and *ready*. Some tricks to help you see what's what:

#### Show me the raw data for a model

```
foo.get('data')
foo.get('data.attributes')
```

#### Get console log output when the record transitions between states

```
record.set("stateManager.enableLogging", true)
```

Comment: Thanks Mike for these tricks. But that's the thing though: it is in state `"rootState.loaded.saved"` so I thought it meant its data has been populated. Yet, it hasn't. When I do `foo.get('data.attributes')`, all the attributes are set to `null`. I should have added: I am inspecting this model in a registerBoundHelper function. Can it be that "within" a template helper, things are a little different (maybe the context is interfering)?

Comment: hard to say for sure. since `{{name}}` is working my best guess is it's timing, like maybe bindings haven't updated yet. can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, in case it helps someone else...

This strange behaviour came from a context issue for the helper. It was pretty "deep" in a view (several nested levels down) and I am using a combination of `{{partial}}` and the new `{{render}}` that you can now use multiple times (on master). I'd lie if I were to say I am totally clear with what was happening, but I tried various contexts switches and it ended up working.

So I guess if you hit something like that, double check your helpers's context...